# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse only works on child pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website built using ASP MVC with Bootstrap, and I have a navbar built using the bootstrap features. Everything works fine, except that when I am on my home page, the collapse feature of the navbar doesn't work. If I navigate to a different page, it works fine. Is there any reason that this would be happening? I am using a Master page for all of these pages, so it seems to me that it would work on all or none.

Here is the code for the navbar.

```
<div style="background-color:#F2F2F2;" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button style="margin-right:20px;" type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-nav" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#crashNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="crashNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top:20px;">
                <li> @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li> @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li> @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried referencing ".navbar-collapse" in the data-target field but that did not help.

Comment: Have you checked your **console** for errors & that jQuery + Bootstrapjs is present on that page?

Comment: Bootstrap and jquery are both present. Other jquery seems to be working fine. I didn't see any errors in console.

Comment: Honestly it's pretty hard to say based on the code/info since there's no way to recreate the problem. My only other (long shot) suggestion would be to clear your browser cache / try a different browser to see if the issue persists.

Comment: I tried clearing my cash and used a different browser, I still have the same issue. Oh well. I will post when I find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for errors in the Javascript console, most of the time when an error occurs Javascript stops behaving so well, since the collapse functionally is handled by Javascript it can not behave like it is supposed to, so you should correct all Javascript errors and test it out again, to access the console:

1. Right click anywhere in page.
2. Go to inspect element.
3. Go to console.

There you'll see the errors.

Comment: I did this, ran through the navbar expand/collapse, and nothing appeared on the console.